# Is this line Instrumentation Amplifier's rail or not?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

A [document](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3344/en/#toc1) related to analog input connections to daq boards depicts the IA of a daq system as in following diagram:

[image]

In all their examples the IA's rail is tied to AIGND. I indicated this with a red arrow above.

Is this line (which I point between the IA and the AIGND) negative rail of the amplifier? Because if so it means they are tying the negative rail to AIGND which is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as the reference for the diff amp.  The amplifier will take the difference between its two inputs, multiply that by some fixed gain, then add that to a reference to make a single ended signal.  That's what diff amps do.  The single-ended output has to be relative to something.  AI GND is that something in your schematic.

It is also possible that this same input is the negative power supply input for the diff amp.  Your schematic doesn't make that clear one way or another.  The datasheet for the part, though, surely goes into detail on all this.

Comment: I thought that reference would be tied ADC's ground rather than the negative power supply rail. I dunno if theres a convention in this business though.